# Slow down door swing in high winds

Tags: door

[image]

I live in a travel trailer.

I have frequent high winds.

Is there a way to prevent my door from flying one way or the other?

Comment: When it's open, can't you hook it back flat against trailer wall?

Comment: Park the trailer with the door on the lee side. Perhaps with one corner pointing into the wind, and the trailing edge of the door downwind of its hinges.

Comment: Consider fitting "controlled motion door hinges". AFAIK they allow a *person* to operate the door normally, but apply friction if the door tries move quickly, such as when caught by a gust of wind.

Comment: @WeatherVane why not incorporate those into an answer?

Comment: @Weather-Vane I rent my home. I do not think my landlord would want to move a trailer. It has electrical power coming in and a hose for my water supply.

Comment: Ask the landlord if you can put up a two fence panels to protect the door from the wind. At right angles to each other so *they* are less likely to be carried off by the wind.

Answer (score 1):

**Shield your entrance with a windbreak.**

Build an L-shaped wood fence frame that leans against the side of your trailer. An L-shape is a very stable free-standing structure.

Fasten uprights with ample space between them for air to get through but close enough to cut the wind speed. You want some air to pass through so the structure will not be blown away in a strong gust.

Your structure doesn't need to be big. A four-foot 'square' footprint should work well. It should allow you enough clearance to carry a package with one arm as you open/close the door.

You might even want to go fancy and make a roof for when it rains.

Good luck.

[image: slatted fence windbreak]

Comment: Great idea about the fence.